# What kind of dev do I need? (cross platform mobile app + Google Cloud Vision API)

Tags: ios, google-cloud-platform

I am writing a job offer to find a dev. The goal is to code the following iOS app:

1. Enables users to take a picture of a list
2. Extracts the text in this picture
3. Compares the extracted items with items on a pre-populated spreadsheet
4. If some extracted items are found in the list, strikes those items out on the picture

I am pretty sure that I need someone experienced with Swift. Although, if the app could be cross-platform, it would be even better.

What skills do I need to expect from this dev?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Vision Api is very simple to implement. I am a student with around 3 years experience and I did not have much problems implementing it on Android for a simple application.

Anyone that can manipulate the basics of the language should be able to implement it.

However, I do not know any swift developer. I do not know anything about swift development. All I can tell is that it is possible.

I would recommend 2-4 student developers. Give them 6 months minimum. Students are familiar with modern tools and won't fear learning a new language such as swift.